# JavaScript slideshow stuck on first photo

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am a Javascript beginner trying to make a simple slideshow using Javascript. From the work I've done, I'm able to produce only one of the five images. The console says nothing is wrong and I am at a loss as to why the other pictures won't show.

```
<script>
    var images = new Array();
        images[0] = new Image();
        images[0].src = "burger1.jpg";
        images[1] = new Image();
        images[1].src = "burger2.jpg";
        images[2] = new Image();
        images[2].src = "burger3.jpg";
        images[3] = new Image();
        images[3].src = "burger4.jpg";
        images[4] = new Image();
        images[4].src = "burger5.jpg";


    var slide = 0;

    function next(){
        if (!document.images) {
          return document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[slide].src
        }       
        if(slide < 5){
          slide++;
        } else{
            slide = 0;
          }
      setTimeout("next()",3000);
    }

    next();

</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="burger1.jpg" id="slideshow" width=100 height=100 />
```

P.S I do not know jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!document.images) {
      return document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[slide].src
    }
```

here !document.images is `[object HTMLCollection]` and you are checking `!` of this use only :

```
if(slide < 5){
          slide++;
        } else{
            slide = 0;
          }
      setTimeout(next,3000);
document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[slide].src
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
   if (!document.images) {
      return document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[slide].src
    }
```

Add

```
document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[slide].src
```

After `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

There's more to fix in your code so I'll try to show you a better approach then just a *quicky*:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tuyigi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```
var slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow'), // Cache your element!
    images = [                            // Create an array of images paths
       "burger1.jpg", 
       "burger2.jpg",
       "burger3.jpg"
    ],
    slide = 0,
    tot = images.length;    // count the total of images

for(var i=0; i<tot; i++){   // preload images (so we don't have to wait for them)
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = images[i];
}


function next() {
  slideshow.src = images[slide++ % tot]; // Modulo operator to loop the counter
  setTimeout(next, 3000);                // Don't wrap `next` in String
}
next();
```